# wxPython wx.NotificationMessage 'BadImplementation (server does not implement operation)'

Tags: linux, wxpython

This is a strange one - I'm just trying to throw together a simple wxpython TaskBarIcon on Fedora 32 but it's throwing segfaults and BadImplementation errors.  I've seen some similar threads but none resolved in a way that fixes my situ.  Is this an Xorg/Wayland packaging mistake in the distro or am I missing something basic?

```
msg=NotificationMessage('test', 'test')
msg.Show(timeout=wx.adv.NotificationMessage.Timeout_Auto)
```

This simple code in an otherwise perfectly healthy TaskBarIcon app yields either a SIGSEGV or the following crash:

```
(livewebcam.py:906900): Gdk-ERROR **: 17:05:27.719: The program 'test.py' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadImplementation (server does not implement operation)'.
  (Details: serial 838 error_code 17 request_code 20 (core protocol) minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Installed versions below.  KDE spin on Xorg (not Wayland).

```
Installed Packages
Name         : xorg-x11-server-Xorg
Version      : 1.20.10
Release      : 1.fc32
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 3.8 M
Source       : xorg-x11-server-1.20.10-1.fc32.src.rpm

python-wxpython4-doc.noarch                        4.0.7-5.fc32  
python3-wxpython4.x86_64                           4.0.7-5.fc32    
python3-wxpython4-media.x86_64                     4.0.7-5.fc32    
python3-wxpython4-webview.x86_64                   4.0.7-5.fc32
wxBase3.x86_64                                     3.0.4-13.fc32
```

Any insight is appreciated - it's jut not my week.

Comment: Back to it just segfaulting again.  So bizarre.

Comment: Take a look at the python package `notify2` for python3

Comment: Yes thank you. Simpler, thread friendly, and window manager agnostic

Answer (score 0):

Giving up as the implementation seems abandoned. Notify2 gets the job done simple enough. Thanks @rolf of saxony.